# Python Pandas Read from column A & B instead of column name

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, loops

I'm relativley new to python
I have a excel file where i can read,Column A "url" and Column B "name".

In the future the columns will have no "column name" so i need it to read from Column A directly  and column B and start iterating from cell 1.

I tried using index_col(0) but can't really seem to get the hang of it.
This is a simple download image script.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\exdata1.xlsx')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
 url = row['url']
 file_name = url.split('/')
r = requests.get(url)  

file_name=(row['name']+".jpeg") 

if r.status_code == 200:
 with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
  f.write(r.content)
  print (file_name)
```

I tried this below without any good result.

```
url = row['index_col(0)'] #0 for excel column "A"
file_name=(row['index_col(1)']+".jpeg")  #1 for excel Column "B"
```

Apreciate any support!

Comment: row['index_col(0)'] search in the column called index_col(0); 
row[index_col(0)] search in the column 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `header=None` as an argument of [**`pandas.read_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and give names to your columns.

Try this :

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
  
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\exdata1.xlsx', header=None, names=['url', 'name'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    url = row['url']
    file_name = url.split('/')
    r = requests.get(url)  
    file_name=(row['name']+'.jpeg') 

    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
            print(file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your files had no columns name pandas assign values to each column such as `Unnamed: 0`, you can check that py printing `df.info` or `df.head()`

you can assign columns names when reading from your file so you df always has columns name:

```
df.rename( columns={"Unnamed: 0" :'url', Unnamed: 0: 'name'}, inplace=True )
```

then you are good to go.